# Why are the outputs not changing/not getting loaded in my single cycle architecture implementation?

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture

I've written the code for the single cycle MIPS Architecture which implements add, sub, multiply and divide. There's a 2D Reg array, A control unit, an ALU. I think I've written it all right, but the opcode I've put in the test bench doesn't seem to be going into the process: the outputs aren't changing at all and I can't understand why. Can anyone tell me why?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////fixed
module registermemory(
input [3:0]Ra, Rb, Wa, Wd,
input write, input clk,
output [3:0] A,B
);

reg [15:0] memarray [3:0]; 

integer i;
initial begin
    for(i=0;i<=15;i=i+1)
        memarray[i]<=4'b0101; ///when the entire 2D array has same value?
end

integer r1,r2,w1;
always@(clk)
begin
r1=Ra;r2=Rb;w1=Wa;
end

assign A = memarray[r1];
assign B = memarray[r2];//assign used outside always. equal to used inside always.
always@(Wd)
    begin   
        if(write)
            memarray[w1]=Wd;
        end

endmodule
///////////////////////////////
module controlblock(opcode,cntrl,Ra,Rb,Wa,write);
input [13:0]opcode;
output reg[1:0]cntrl;
output reg[3:0]Ra;
output reg[3:0]Rb;
output reg[3:0]Wa;
output reg write; //control signal tells that register has to be written in reg file


always@(opcode) ///why @opcode tho?
begin
cntrl=opcode[13:12];            
Ra=opcode[11:8];
Rb=opcode[7:4];
Wa=opcode[3:0];
write=1; //why tho?
end

endmodule
///////////////////////////////
module alu_arith(input[3:0]A, input[1:0] cntrl,
input clk,  
input[3:0]B,
output reg[3:0]Wd
);

always@(clk)
begin
case(cntrl)
    00:Wd=A+B;
    01:Wd=A-B;
    10:Wd=A*B;
    11:Wd=A/B;
default: Wd=4'b0000;
endcase
end

endmodule

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module concat(input [0:13]opcode, input clk, output[3:0]Wd);

wire[3:0]Ra;wire[3:0]Rb;wire[3:0]Wa;wire written;wire[1:0]cntrl;
wire[3:0]A;wire[3:0]B;wire[3:0]Wd;

controlblock a1(opcode,cntrl,Ra,Rb,Wa,write); //

registermemory a2(Ra, Rb, Wa, Wd,write,clk,A,B
); //

alu_arith a3(A,cntrl,clk,B,Wd); //
endmodule
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module testbench;
reg clk;
reg[13:0]opcode;
wire[3:0]Wd;
wire[1:0] cntrl;
reg[3:0]A,B;

concat a4(opcode,clk,Wd);

initial
clk=0;

always
#2 clk=!clk;
initial begin
    $display("\ttime \tclk  \tcntrl \tA  \tB  \tWd ");
    $monitor("%d,\t   \t%b   \t%b   \t%b   \t%b   \t%b",
    $time, clk, cntrl, A, B, Wd);

    #10 opcode=14'b00010010110100;
    #20 opcode=14'b01100010101010;
end

initial
#50 $finish;    


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared `memarray` incorrectly as a 16-bit wide by 4 word deep memory.  You want a 4-bit wide by 16 deep:

```
reg [3:0] memarray [0:15];
```

When I make this change, I see the `Wd` output changing.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I made that change and Wd is indeed changing but cntrl, A, and B are still not changing. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: You're welcome.  In `testbench`, you did not assign cntrl, A, and B any values.  That is why they don't change.  A and B do change inside `concat`.  You really should use a waveform viewer, as I mentioned in the comment.